# Symmetricds one way setup

Tags: replication, firebird, database-replication, symmetricds

I am a little confused on how to setup a one way 3 tier replication using symmetricds.

What I am trying to setup is something like this:

[image: Setup]

The company server is not connected to the internet and as you can see it's one way, and basically the final tier is a readonly database used by a web application .

- How to setup this 2 steps replication?
- Do I need to install Symmetric (java . etc) in each server?

Need some guideline here, thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zack,

It sounds like at a minimum you would want 2 SymmetricDS installations.  One for your company server and intermediate server. If these are on the same local network a multi-homed (local node) setup would work.  I would make the company server the master node and the intermediate a local node in the same installation.  The final installation of SymmetricDS would be close to your DB internet server (you want a reliable JDBC connection here).   Then I would setup 3 node groups (ex: server, intermediate, web).  I would build group links:

intermediate pulls from server (for your data)
intermediate pushes to server (for heartbeats and config)
intermediate pushes to web (for your data and allows you to keep a firewall in place from outside connections in).
intermediate pulls from web (for heartbeats and config)

From here you can select your tables for replication and should be all set.

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a look at the demo [here](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.9/html/tutorials.html) to become more familiar with the basic configuration.
2. Start off by syncing your company and intermediate server.
3. Once you are syncing your company and intermediate server, add your third tier. Additional information on adding multiple tiers can be found [here](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.9/html/user-guide.html#_multi_tiered_synchronization).

SymmetricDS uses JDBC drivers to communicate with the database. JDBC is not intended to run over the internet. This is why SymmetricDS should be installed local to each DB instance.

It is possible to point one SymmetricDS instance to two different DB's. You should only do this if both DBs exist on the same network. More information on adding multiple nodes [here](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.9/html/user-guide.html#_add_node).